# Not being able to test hover styles with jest-dom and styled components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, styled-components, jest-dom

I'm facing an issue while trying to test my Button component, I'll let down the code from the respective files alongside some screenshots.

Basically, I have an `active` and a `hover` style and it is being applied correctly on the application but when it comes to tests something is happening. Running the tests with the file as it is by default the test fails and the log says that the style applied is the `active` one, which shouldn't be happening.

When I comment the `active` the tests run and pass normally as it should pass. I made some tests on the actual application and everything is happening as expected as I'll show on the screenshot of the DOM.

Enough talking, someone has any idea about what's causing this issue?

```
// Button.styles.ts

import styled from "styled-components";

export const Button = styled.button`
  width: 100%;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primary};
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.text.primary};
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }

  &:active {
    transform: translateY(0.3rem);
  }
`;

export const Icon = styled.div`
  margin-right: 0.8rem;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

```
// Button.test.tsx

import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import Button from "./Button";
import Theme from "../../Theme";

describe("Button", () => {
  it("should render with correct children", () => {
    render(
      <Theme>
        <Button>Entrar</Button>
      </Theme>
    );

    const button = screen.getByText(/entrar/i);
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("should not render any children if isLoading is passed as true", () => {
    render(
      <Theme>
        <Button isLoading={true}>Entrar</Button>
      </Theme>
    );

    const button = screen.queryByText(/entrar/i);
    expect(button).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("should the proper style when user hover over it", () => {
    //FIXME: Não está funcionando
    render(
      <Theme>
        <Button>Entrar</Button>
      </Theme>
    );

    const button = screen.getByText(/entrar/i);
    userEvent.hover(button);
    expect(button).toHaveStyle({
      backgroundColor: "#000000",
      transform: "scale(1.05)"
    });
  });
});

it("should the proper style when user click over it", () => {
  render(
    <Theme>
      <Button>Entrar</Button>
    </Theme>
  );

  const button = screen.getByText(/entrar/i);
  userEvent.click(button);
  expect(button).toHaveStyle("transform: scale(0.95)");
});
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "club-clothing",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings=0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest --passWithNoTests",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "cypress": "npx cypress open",
    "generate": "plop --plopfile ./generators/plopfile.cjs",
    "postinstall": "npx husky install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.1.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "firebase": "^10.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^9.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.26",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.61.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.61.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "cypress": "^12.17.2",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.1",
    "git-commit-msg-linter": "^5.0.4",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.4",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "plop": "^3.1.2",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.0",
    "vite-plugin-environment": "^1.1.3"
  }
}
```

The error:

```
Button › should the proper style when user hover over it

    expect(element).toHaveStyle()

    - Expected

    - backgroundColor: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    - transform: scale(1.05);
    + transform: translateY(0.3rem);

      37 |     const button = screen.getByText(/entrar/i);
      38 |     userEvent.hover(button);
    > 39 |     expect(button).toHaveStyle({
         |                    ^
      40 |       backgroundColor: "#000000",
      41 |       transform: "scale(1.05)"
      42 |     });

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Button/Button.test.tsx:39:20)
```

Note: I tested the `userEvent` with the `await` keyword but still the same outcome, the wrong style.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm a crazy nut around testing, but I think testing if your CSS hover style applies correctly is taking things a little bit too far. One reason to do as much as possible in CSS vs Javascript is you don't need to test it. Also your test is testing the hover style on click, but you're using click. See https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/convenience#hover

Comment: Got it, so I don't actually need test it. I don't know why but somehow I caught myself finding it a useful test and trying to test it. I didn't have this POV of "I don't need to test it", I find it funny, though hahaha! Thank you for your answer, much love!

Comment: Hover styles usually aren't make or break in most applications. If it is in yours, by all means, test it.